# How to align local (git) and remote (GitHub) project paths?

Tags: git, github

I'm only using a single branch (`main`). On my local repo, my project is inside `foo` directory, but on GitHub my project is inside `foo/foo` directory. When I do `git push` or `git pull` everything is up to date.

How could I remove a foo level on Github to have my project inside `foo` instead of `foo/foo`?

EDIT:

Since the question is closed and answer option is now unavailable, I'll put the solution here:

`$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel` gave `~/Git`.

In order to have `~/Git/foo` instead, I did `$ git init` from `~/Git/foo`

Then,

- `$ git remote add foo https://github.com/myaccount/foo`
- `$ git checkout -b main`
- `$ git add *`
- `$ git commit`
- `$ git push --set-upstream foo main -f`

Comment: Please tell me the needed details so I can add them.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the lack of information, I'll have to make a bit of a wild guess.

You are likely to have `git init`ed your project in the parent directory of the project, rather than inside the project directory.

You can fix this by:

1. Go to the parent directory (`cd ..`)
2. Move the child directory's content to the parent directory (`mv foo/* .`)
3. Commit the change (`git add .` and `git commit -m "message"`)
4. You can now use the parent directory as the project root.

My assumption about the parent directory being the repository's root could be wrong.
You can check if this is true by running `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`, which will print the top-level directory of the current Git repository.

Comment: From `foo`, `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` gives `/home/crocefisso/Git`, which is where all my git repos are.

Comment: @crocefisso yes, that is your mistake. It should show the path to the `foo` folder. You ran `git init` inside `/home/crocefisso/Git` instead of inside the `foo` folder.

Comment: Since you mentioned that there are already other projects in the parent - `Git/` directory, I'd suggest just running `git init` again inside the `foo` directory and creating a new repository. You can remove the repository created at the `Git/` directory by deleting the `.git/` directory.

Comment: `git init` from `Git/` did nothing. `git init` from `Git/foo/` made `main` branch disappear (`git branch` now gives nothing). And when I do `git push` it says `fatal: No configured push destination.` But now `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` says `/home/crocefisso/Git/foo`

Comment: I did `git remote add` to fix this but now `git push` says `Fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.`

Comment: Then I did `git checkout -b main` and now when I push I have `error: src refspec main does not match any` and `error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myaccount/foo`.

Comment: While `LANG=EN git checkout -b main` gives `Switched to a new branch 'main'`, `git branch` still gives nothing when it should give `* main`...

Comment: Thanks for your help @WieeRd, it helped me solve the issue. I put the solution in the question edit.